# Node.JS and SSL certificate

Tags: node.js, ssl, ssl-certificate

I was running my node.js app with autosigned certificates.
That was working pretty well, except I was forced to accept certificate every time I opened chrome.
Then I bought an SSL certificate (actually a wildcard) from Gandi.
And I'm currently trying to put the certificates in my nodeapp.

```
var http = require( "http" );
var https = require( "https" );
var fs = require( "fs" );
var url  = require( "url" );
var crypto = require("crypto");

function start(route,handle) {
    function onRequest(request, response) {
            var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
            //console.log("Requete recue pour le chemin "+pathname+".");
            route(handle, pathname, response, request);
    }

    var options = {
            key: fs.readFileSync('privatekey.pem').toString(),
            cert: fs.readFileSync('certificate.pem').toString()
    };

    var app = https.createServer(options,onRequest);
    var io = require('socket.io').listen( app );
    io.set('log level', 1);
    app.listen( 8080 );
    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {


    });
    console.log("Server's launching");
}
```

With the signed certificate, server's launching and running but everytime I call

```
https://mydomain/ or https://mydomain:8080/
```

I get a

```
Erreur 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR) : Erreur de protocole SSL
```

Any idea ? 
How can I have more infos regarding the error ?
Any help much appreciated...

Comment: Have you [checked Chrome's SSL version options](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/gWOCNmiVtfQ) ?

Comment: Yes, I tried with SSL2 and SSL3, SSL2 only, and the default one, SSL3 only, always the same error.

Comment: You shouldn't need the .toString() calls on .readFileSync for the key and cert, though I don't think that's the cause of the problem here.

Comment: Yes, that was "just another try", as I saw some examples doing this way.

Comment: No more idea ? I'm kind of desperate...

Comment: @Morgan, I don't have a purchased cert that I can try. The places I would start are: make sure the cert is trusted on your machine, try a different port (is port 8080 in use for http?), and disable any other web servers. According to [this post on AWS](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=291276), Apache `ServerAlias` entries may be a problem. e.g. if Apache is listening on port 8080, it may cause SSL to fail. Try some port like 9001.

Comment: I only have node running on port 8080, rerouting to 443 because I can't have node directly listen to 443. netstat gives me only ports 25, 22 and 8080 opened for listening. I can't find anything related to Gandi in the certificates of my machine...

Comment: Hmm, even with the crt installed on my machine, i get the same error...

Comment: Have you tried installing the intermediate certificates that came with your wildcard from Gandi? You can try [SSLTools Manager](http://www.ssltools.com/manager) and that will auto install intermediate certs if you are running Windows